# how can i avoid repeating continuously on keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a code for keydown event.my code works like,
when i press arrowdown key (40)this function verticalSlideUp(); start to work.
but when i press this key (40) twice, and press key (38) then key(40) works two times and after finish this, key(38) start to work.

**but what i want to do is** : when i press a key(40)(38)(13) any of them, then 
**immediately other function will stop.and current function will start**.

**NOTE** : i have follow this answer in stackoverflow

**How can I avoid autorepeated keydown events in JavaScript?**

This in my code :

```
var allowed = true;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.repeat != undefined) {
    allowed = !e.repeat;
  }
  if (!allowed) return;
  allowed = false;

  if (controlsEnabled) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      allowed = true;
      verticalSlideDown();
      console.log("pressed key for Down : " + e.keyCode);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      allowed = true;
      verticalSlideUp();
      console.log("pressed key for Up: " + e.keyCode);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      allowed = true;
      var div = $(".scroll-inner-container");
      console.log("pressed key for stop : " + e.keyCode);
      div.stop();
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in functional way. Easy to test and encouraging code reusable.

For example:

```js
const ENTER = 13;
const RIGHT = 39;
const DOWN = 40;

const once = (fn) => {
  let chached = null;

  return function (key) {
    return chached === key ? void 0 : ((chached = key), fn.apply(this, arguments))
  }
}

const logger = (log) => (x) => log(x);

const included = (keys) => (key) => keys.indexOf(key) > -1;

$(document).ready(() => {
  const allowedKeys = included([ENTER, RIGHT, DOWN]);
  const log = logger(console.log);
  
  const program = once((x) => {
     switch (x) {
       case ENTER:
         log(x)
         break;
       case RIGHT:
         log(x)
         break;
       case DOWN:
         log(x)
         break;
       default:
         log('Unhandled keys')
     }
  });
  
  
  $(document).keydown((e) => {
    if (allowedKeys(e.keyCode)) program(e.keyCode)
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Tom ,when i press a key(40)(38)(13) any of them, then immediately other function will stop.and current function will start..
is that possible ..?

Comment: You mean to stop the current running animation? You just need to add the div.stop() on beginning of each function (inside verticalSlideUp/verticalSlideDown). You already have it on keyCode 13.

Comment: i mean when i press any key of them then only this function will be executed.if press (40) and after press (38) then this key(40)function will be stop.and this(30) function will be start immediately.
here my  code link  [this is jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Masud001/z8mstp67/)

Comment: Yes I think what you mean, how to stop the animation, If I get it correctly. You need to stop it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/z8mstp67/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable that remembers the keycode of the pressed key, and the compare it in the listener function:

```
var allowed = true;
var previousKeyPress = null;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.repeat != undefined) {
    allowed = !e.repeat;
  }
  if (!allowed) return;
  allowed = false;

  if (controlsEnabled) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38 && previousKeyPress != 38) {
      allowed = true;
      verticalSlideDown();
      console.log("pressed key for Down : " + e.keyCode);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40 && previousKeyPress != 40) {
      allowed = true;
      verticalSlideUp();
      console.log("pressed key for Up: " + e.keyCode);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13  && previousKeyPress != 13) {
      allowed = true;
      var div = $(".scroll-inner-container");
      console.log("pressed key for stop : " + e.keyCode);
      div.stop();
    }
    previousKeyPress = e.keyCode;
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you @Catalin .your code works.but let me explain,
let this `verticalSlideUp()` will take to finish 1 minute.if i press key(40) then this fnction will start. after 10 second later if i press key(38) then previous function will stop and current function will start..it's like a robot.when i press a key then other function will stop,and current function   will start. is it possible ..?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible, but of course it depends entirely on your `verticalSlideUp` and `verticalSlideDown` functions, what they do and how you can stop them. A Fiddle with a simple working example would be best.

Comment: thank you very much @Catalin  this is my Jsfiddle link
[this is link](https://jsfiddle.net/Masud001/qjn4k1wo/)

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the last key, try the following

```
var allowed = true;
var last_key;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.repeat != undefined) {
    allowed = !e.repeat;
  }
  if (!allowed) return;
  allowed = false;

  if (e.keyCode == last_key){
     return;
  }

  if (controlsEnabled) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
      allowed = true;
      verticalSlideDown();
      console.log("pressed key for Down : " + e.keyCode);
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
      allowed = true;
      verticalSlideUp();
      console.log("pressed key for Up: " + e.keyCode);
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      allowed = true;
      var div = $(".scroll-inner-container");
      console.log("pressed key for stop : " + e.keyCode);
      div.stop();
    }

    last_key = e.keyCode;
  }

});
```

Comment: thank you @Svetoslav. i have tried your code also.your code also works.
But i want to do like,whatever the situation,if i press key(30)(40)(13) immediately other function will stop.and current function will start.